# No me funciona el boton de translate de google

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

tengo un problema y es que google provee de un codigo para hacer un boton de traducir  automaticamente la pagina a diferentes idiomas. Cuando la carga en el xamp me va todo bien miren asi aparece
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando voy a cargarla en la pagina web no me sale el boton y aparece asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo a ver si podeis averiguar que pasa

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> Google Translater for Website </title> 
</head> 
<body>
<h2>Your Web Page</h2>
<p>Click on the dropdown button to translate.</p>
<p>Translate this page:</p>

<div id="google_translate_elemenst"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? 
cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box. 
</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Diria que es porque tienes la linea partida donde dice `cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>`... mira de subirla y pegarla a la anterior y ya nos cuentas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale parece ser que no lo cogi bien todo el codigo pero asi si funciona

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en' }, 
'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"
src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? 
cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

y luego le sacas con el div

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```